# How to make div "margin-bottom" equal to another div height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code (make element ".aaa" margin-bottom equal to element ".bbb" height):

```
$('.aaa').css( 'margin-bottom', $('.bbb').css('height'));
```

It works but... how to make it to work dynamically if ".bbb" elements have varying heights?

I am very sorry, but I do not know how to explain it better.

**Edit:** Sorry, this is a code sample to better understand what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/d77n9ajx/1/

Should be like the first one.

Comment: use the event on change in the element bbb to set the margin-bottom of aaa element

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but actually, I was hoping that someone will give me some sample code. I do not have a clue how to do it myself :( Thank you.

Comment: How you change the height of the element bbb? you have an event that is fired to change the height?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
$('.aaa').css('margin-bottom', $('#bbb').height() + 'px');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery method `outerHeight()` to get `.bbb` height.

> .outerHeight( [includeMargin ] ) Returns: Number
>
> Description: Get the
>   current computed height for the first element in the set of matched
>   elements, including padding, border, and optionally margin. Returns a
>   number (without "px") representation of the value or null if called on
>   an empty set of elements.

After you get .bbb height you assign it to `.aaa` `margin-bottom` property with `.css()` function.

---

**Code Snippet:**

```js
(function() {
  var a = $(".aaa"),
    b = $(".bbb");

  var bOuterHeight = b.outerHeight();

  a.css("margin-bottom", bOuterHeight);

  var aMarginBottom = a.css("margin-bottom");
  console.log("bbb height:" + b.outerHeight() + " aaa margin bottom:" + aMarginBottom);
})();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  height: 50px;
}
.aaa {
  background-color: gold;
}
.bbb {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aaa"></div>
<div class="bbb"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only an example, the objective is that you add the code:

> $('.aaa').css( 'margin-bottom', $('.bbb').css('height'));

in the event that resize the element bbb

```js
function ChangeDivSize(){
  $('.bbb').height(100);
  $('.aaa').css( 'margin-bottom', $('.bbb').css('height'));
}
```

```css
.aaa{
 background-color:red; 
  height:100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
.bbb{
  background-color: blue;
  height:50px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aaa"></div>
<div class="bbb"></div>
<input type="button" value="Change Div Size" onclick="ChangeDivSize()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not very neat, but it should work.

```js
var previousHeight = null;
setInterval(function()
{
  var height = $('.bbb').height();
  if (height == previousHeight)
    return;

  $('.aaa').css('margin-bottom', height);
  previousHeight = height;

}, 10);

animate();

function animate()
{
  $('.bbb').animate({ height: '0px' }, 1000, function()
  {
    $('.bbb').animate({ height: '100px' }, 1000, animate);
  });
}
```

```css
.aaa {
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
}

.bbb {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aaa"></div>
<div class="bbb"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have more .aaa and .bbb elements you should use each().

```js
var calculateMargin = function(){
  // Make ".aaa" margin-bottom equal to ".bbb" height
  $('.aaa').each(function(){
    $(this).css( 'margin-bottom', $(this).next('.bbb').css('height'));
  });
};

calculateMargin();

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  calculateMargin();
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
.aaa {
  width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.bbb {
  position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="aaa"></div>
  <div class="bbb">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non recusandae ipsa cum eum aspernatur sint eligendi.       Accusantium, veniam, porro voluptatum dolorem deleniti laborum sapiente...
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="aaa"></div>
  <div class="bbb">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non recusandae ipsa cum eum...
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="aaa"></div>
  <div class="bbb">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non recusandae ipsa cum eum aspernatur sint eligendi.       Accusantium, veniam, porro...
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="aaa"></div>
  <div class="bbb">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="aaa"></div>
  <div class="bbb">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit....
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="aaa"></div>
  <div class="bbb">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non recusandae ipsa cum eum aspernatur sint eligendi.       Accusantium, veniam, porro voluptatum dolorem...
  </div>
</div>
```

or if .bbb will not always be the next sibling of .aaa, but will be within the same container; than:

```
$('.aaa').each(function(){
    $(this).css( 'margin-bottom', $(this).parent().find('.bbb').first().css('height'));
});
```

Both will work in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for your problem.

**The code properly resizes `aaa` margin-bottom in case your `bbb` div changes as well.**

HTML

```
<div class="aaa">Test the code</div>

<div class="bbb">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        var bheight=$('.bbb').height();

        $('.aaa').css('margin-bottom',bheight);

        new ResizeSensor($('.bbb'), function() {
                bheight=$('.bbb').height();   
                $('.aaa').css('margin-bottom',bheight);
            }); //Function runs incase bbb div changes size
        });
    </script>
```

Please do include the following scripts to run your code:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ElementQueries.js"></script>
<script src="js/ResizeSensor.js"></script>
```

These `.js` files are my local versions. You do download it for yourself. You can find `ElementQueries.js` and `ResizeSensor.js` in following link:http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/

Hope this satisfies your concern!!

Answer (score -1):

Based on @mbadeveloper try this:

```
$( ".bbb" ).resize(function() {
     $( ".aaa" ).css( "margin-bottom" , $( ".bbb" ).height()); 
});
```

Hope the syntax is correct :/

Comment: The resize event is only triggered from the window.

Comment: I added a link to fiddle to better understand what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/d77n9ajx/